# Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: 'null' in Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, null

I have a following query which insert data into mysql using java.

It gives me this error

```
Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: 'null' for column 'lastEventTime' at row 1
```

The `lastEventTime` is set to be a nullable `datetime` type with default as `NULL`. Unfortunately when I run the same query in phpmyadmin it accept and data get inserted into the table. What is the solution for java then?

My of part codes is as below.

Comment: your insert query is wrong? you want insert or update?

Comment: I am very sure its an insert and I have tested in phpmyadmin it works perfectly.

Comment: The error message says that `lastEventTime='null'` is not valid. Assuming the field is nullable, I would suggest `lastEventTime=NULL`

Comment: The problem sometime I have a proper value for lastEventTime which is not Null so how to decide when to put the 'quote and not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single quotes (`'`) denote string literals. Here, you didn't mean you insert the string `'null'`, but an actual `null` value - just drop the quotes:

```
INSERT INTO tblDetails 
SET    eID=1010,entID=2,tID=65,eDateTime='2014-12-04 14:34:44',lastEventTime=null
```

Moreover, unless `lsatEventTime` has an undesirable default value, you could just drop the reference to it altogether and let the database use the default (`null`):

```
INSERT INTO tblDetails 
SET    eID=1010,entID=2,tID=65,eDateTime='2014-12-04 14:34:44'
```

EDIT:
To answer the question asked in the comments, this can be done even when dynamically constructing the `insert` statement. Just take the following line:

```
"',lastEventTime='"+rs10d.getString("lastEventTime")+"'";
```

... and add some logic to check for `null`s:

```
"',lastEventTime=" + (rs10d.getString("lastEventTime") == null ? 
                      "null" : 
                      "'"+rs10d.getString("lastEventTime")+"'");
```

Comment: Hi mureinik the problem is that I read the value of lastEventTime from another select query so in normal case it will be date time value. So that is why I have the single quote ' there? So what should I do if there is a proper datetime value is available ?

Comment: Please share your code - it's impossible to provide any useful answer without the specifics.

Comment: I have put my snipet of codes in my question. Where I show first the select query and then in the while loop is where I do the insert.

Comment: The interesting part is the part where you construct the insert statement - can you add that too please?

Comment: I dont get your syntax I know what you saying if its null then put null else put the actual value. How to read your syntax ?

Comment: This is a [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#Java). Basically, the form is `condition ? valueIfTrue : valueIfFalse`.

Comment: Ok I got it now. What is your advice to leave it as null the datetime value or put a default value of '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ?

Comment: I'd leave it as `null`. It's much easier to handle later.

Comment: Ok thank you so I am doing the right method to be null.

Comment: Something have gone wrong. I notice my whole query string is null value any reason for it ?

Comment: Thank you yes that was the problem